# Excel formula changes when external source is updated

Tags: excel

Every row in the Q column computes the quantity of prime numbers(up to 9) in the 15 numbers in the same row. These 15 ones come from an external txt file.

Then, when I update the txt and refresh it in Excel, the formula on the last row changes so that it does not work the expected way.

It's hard to explain so here`s a picture:
[image]

Can anyone help me with this one?

Comment: Either manually (like in the print, where Excel correctly imported the 1,2,3... sequence) or automatically...the file format does not change. It is 15 numbers between 1 and 25 per line.

Comment: Sorry, did not understand what you said, but the txt is connected as 'external data' on Excel. It does not lose a line when a new one gets inserted(always at the bottom).

Answer (score 0):

Click on **Properties** under **Data** tab
[image: Click on **Properties** under **Data** tab]

Click on "Overwrite existing cells with new data, clear unused cells"
[image: Click on "Overwrite existing cells with new data, clear unused cells"]